# Regression Modelling of Linear, Exponential, and Power Curves in R

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models

Please note this is cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427649/regression-modelling-of-linear-exponential-and-power-curves

I am trying to model reaction time (and other) data across trials (trial 1-5) using different mathematical functions. Specifically I model linear, exponential, and power functions using linear mixed effect models by transforming data and use AIC/BIC to compare fits:

```
Linear: lmer(ReactionTime ~ Trial + (Trial | Subjects), data = lmerdata)

Exponential: lmer(log(ReactionTime) ~ Trial + (Trial | Subjects), data = lmerdata)

Power: lmer(log(ReactionTime) ~ log(Trial) + (Trial | Subjects), data = lmerdata)
```

By doing this, the exponential and power equations imply a different distribution for errors than the linear equation. The consequence of this is inflated exponential and power function fits relative to the linear fit.

Is there a way to account for this using lmer()? Alternatively, how would this be done using non-linear mixed effects modelling? I've attempted to do it with nlme(), nlmer(), glmer() but all methods end up running into issues (e.g., do not converge).

Here is sample data:

```
#Create Empty Matrix
lmerdata <- matrix(NA, 20, 3)

#Add Participant IDs
lmerdata[, 1] <- rep(1:4, 5)

#Add Trial Counts
lmerdata[, 2] <- as.numeric(sort(rep(1:5, 4)))

#Add Reaction Time Data
lmerdata[, 3] <- c(2.184308,2.754287,2.396167,1.305267,1.943866,1.70844,2.586035,1.261954,1.768063,1.76659,2.242142,1.489634,1.62544,1.677268,2.378175,1.550744,1.481052,1.424327,1.738102,1.247097)

#Name Columns
colnames(lmerdata) <- c('Subjects', 'Trial', 'ReactionTime')

#Convert to Data Frame
lmerdata <- as.data.frame(lmerdata)

#Turn Subjects into Factor
lmerdata$Subjects <- as.factor(lmerdata$Subjects)
```